# Does fit_generator loads different set of data at every epoch?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I understand that one epoch usually indicates one iteration of every training samples. Keras `fit_generator` function got a parameter `sample_per_epoch`. Let's say I have 20000 training samples and I have decided to set `samples_per_epoch` as 5000. What happens in the next epoch ? Will it pick same set of 5000 training samples or does it starts with new random set ?

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to fit using same model object then i will take from 5001 when your in the same session, Else it will again starts with 1st epoch.
After session completes,model object will get expire.To avoid such issue you can save your model so that you can use it and it will starts from 5001 epoch. It will be applicable for same dataset